# EXTRACT the date and time - (Teradata)

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata

I am trying to extract the date and time from a field in Teradata.

The field in question is:

```
VwNIMEventFct.EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP
```

Here is what the data look like:

```
01/02/2012 12:18:59.306000
```

I'd like the date and time only.

I have tried using `EXTRACT(Date`, `EXTRACT(DAY_HOUR` and a few others with no success.

`DATE_FORMAT()` does not appear to work since I'm on Teradata.

How would I select the date and time from `VwNIMEventFct.EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: what data type is VwNIMEventFct.EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the datatype of EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP is a TIMESTAMP, it's simple Standard SQL:

```
CAST(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
CAST(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS TIME)
```

If it's a CHAR you need to apply a FORMAT, too:

```
CAST(CAST(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'dd/mm/yyyyBhh:mi:SS.s(6)') AS DATE)
CAST(CAST(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'dd/mm/yyyyBhh:mi:SS.s(6)') AS TIME)
```

**Edit:**

For simply changing the display format you need to add a FORMAT and a CAST to a string:

```
CAST(CAST(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDHHMI') AS CHAR(12))
or
CAST(CAST(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS') AS CHAR(14))
```

If you don't care about display, just want to truncate the seconds:

```
EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP - (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP) * INTERVAL '1.000000' SECOND)
```

Working with timestamps is a bit tricky :-)

Comment: I checked the data type and it's timestamp(6). What does 6 mean?
I tried adding in as you suggested but I really need them concatenated to be date and time.
I tried 
SELECT CAST(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)+CAST(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS TIME)  AS theDate
But error message "Invalid operation with Ansi Datetime". It did cast as date when I used only the first part. Is there a way to cast it as date and time in a oner?

Comment: TIMESTAMP(6) means six fractional digits, i.e. micro seconds. But I don't get what you mean by "concatenated to be date and time", this will be a TIMESTAMP column again. Could you elaborate?

Comment: So currently the results of say SELECT CAST(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDHHMM')  return 04/18/2014 12:20:44.384000
I need that minus the .384000

Comment: Ok, you just want to format in a different way. FORMAT was implemented decades ago for reports in BTEQ, for any other client you need to add another CAST to a (VAR)CHAR. I'll edit my answer...

Comment: Thanks for the info in your edit. Before I implement it:
1) The data type is a timestamp.
2) If I cast as CHAR(12) will that result in a non timestamp result?
2b) Because I'd like to manipulate the data based on date/time but grouped at the date, hour and minute level? Am I making sense?

Comment: I tried 
SELECT CAST(CAST(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS') AS CHAR(12)) AS dateTime2
And the result is like this 201403102154. Is that a timestamp still?

Comment: If you cast it to it's not a timestamp any more. But you can still GROUP BY it. Or you use the 2nd query to truncate the seconds

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but I've struggled with this too. Try:

```
CAST(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP(0))
```

The result will be

```
01/02/2012 12:18:59
```

The datatype will still be timestamp, but it will just be the date and time with no microseconds (looks just like a datetime object in Microsoft SQL).