# Convert timestamp into date and time Sql

Tags: sql, teradata, epoch

How can i convert a timestamp (formatted this way: 1,437,538,735.00) into date and time (such as 2016-11-23 14:00:00) in Teradata SQL?

Thank you!

Comment: You can just use `CAST(timestampData As Date)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EXTRACT the date and time - (Teradata)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506057/extract-the-date-and-time-teradata)

Comment: @CoderofCode no it is not duplicate of that. here requirement is to convert epoch to teradata timestamp

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25378258/2527905

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Unix format for the time, so it is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.  Something like this should work:

```
select timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + interval '1437538735' second
```

I don't have Teradata on hand to specifically test the syntax.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm very new to Teradata so I'm no sure of the rest of the syntax. Would it be:CAST(timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + interval '1437538735') AS FINAL_DATE

Comment: problem is teradata not accepting more than 9999 with interval clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select CAST(DATE '1970-01-01' + (1437538735 / 86400) AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + ((1437538735 MOD 86400) * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND) td_ts
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + 1437538735 * interval '0 00:00:01' day to second
```

P.s.
With this syntax you can use a colum/expression instead of the hard-coded value

Comment: Should be `select timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + 1437538735 * interval '0000 00:00:01' day to second`, but it will fail anyway because it's more than 27 years :-)

Comment: Damn. Mobile. OOO :-)

Comment: @dnoeth, right of course  regarding the 27 years but my other mistake was using`day(4)` in the first place. The bracket do no apply to literals.