# How to retrieve date in a different format - SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a column with date in this format: `2017-01-31 23:07:50.569000`

In my query, I am using

```
select * 
from tableA
where progress_datetime between 20200319 and 20200324
```

However, this does not retrieve the list of rows between those days and gives an invalid error. Does anyone know how I can retrieve the correct date without having to input the entire time in hours, minutes and seconds?

I am using TERADATA.

Thank you.

Comment: What data type is the column? In what away does it "not seem to work"?

Comment: If the column is storing as date data type, I think you can just use `between '20200319' and '20200324'` include the `'` so it will not treat it as a integer.

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: It's saying it's invalid date time, I only want to know everything between 20200319 and 20200324 regardless of the time.

Comment: It's best to use ANSI date constant syntax like  `date'2020-03-19'`. Note that the value `2017-01-31 23:07:50.569000` is not a `DATE`, it may be `TIMESTAMP(6)` - but Teradata will implicitly `CAST` the `TIMESTAMP` as a `DATE` (i.e. truncate the time portion) when you are comparing with a `DATE` value.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the strings to a date type:

```
select * 
from tableA
where progress_datetime between date '2020-03-19' and date '2020-03-24'
```

By not modifying the data of `progress_datetime`, an index on that column wold be able to be used, and even if not, it will be much more efficient than having to calculate the result of a function on `progress_datetime` for every row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tableA
where  
CAST(progress_datetime as DATE)
between '2020-03-19' and '2020-03-24'
```

The column `progress_datetime` looks like it is of type Timestamp(6). The above cast converts it into ANSI date format.

You can find more info on Extracting the date and time from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506057/extract-the-date-and-time-teradata/23509212).
Similarly you can read this [documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/UH3h4t2OClLORLJzEJf9yw).